# Redux Saga not being cancelled

Tags: redux-saga

I have this type of composition of my sagas - a race between:

- some long polling fetching
- cancellation action that's triggered manually by the user

```
export function* doPollingSaga() {  
  try {
    while (true) {
      const res = yield call(fetchData, {})
      if(res) {
        yield put(saveResultsActionCreator(res))
        if(weHaveEverythingWeWanted) {
          break;
        }
      }
      yield delay(POLLING_DELAY);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(doSomeErrorReportingAndFinishActionCreator());
  } finally {
    if (yield cancelled()) {
      yield put(doSomePostCancelActionCreator());
    }
  }
}

export default function*() {
  yield race([
    take(ActionTypes.CANCEL),
    all([
      takeLatest(ActionTypes.DO_POLLING, doPollingSaga),
      // some more other sagas here
    ]),
  ]);
}
```

but when I dispatch `ActionTypes.CANCEL` from one of the UI components - nothing happens

In redux devtools I see that it's being dispatched correctly, but polling doesn't stop, `doPollingSaga` continues like nothing happened.

Inside `doPollingSaga` `yield cancelled() === false` all the time.

I've also tried replacing `while(true)` with  `while(!(yield cancelled()))` but no effect as well.

From the [docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation/#automatic-cancellation) I assume that everything inside `all([...])` should be cancelled when `ActionType.CANCEL` wins the `race`

Not sure if I'm missing something important about cancellation of sagas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the cause is in nesting order of `race` and `takeLatest`. The latter forks given saga, making it cancel-proof. You have to either listen to cancel actions inside the polling loop, or make a `race` inside the `takeLatest`:

```
function* cancellableSaga() {
  yield race([take('cancel_polling'), call(doPollingSaga)]);
}
```

[The whole example](https://%20https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-saga-template-k8vajv?file=index.js)